# jTidy returns nothing after tidying HTML

Tags: java, android, html, tidy, jtidy

I have come across a very annoying problem when using jTidy (on Android). I have found jTidy works on every HTML Document I have tested it against, except the following:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
      <html lang="en">
       <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />

         <!-- Always force latest IE rendering engine & Chrome Frame 
              Remove this if you use the .htaccess -->
         <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />

         <title>templates</title>
         <meta name="description" content="" />
         <meta name="author" content="" />

         <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0" />

         <!-- Replace favicon.ico & apple-touch-icon.png in the root of your domain and delete these references -->
      <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/apple-touch-icon.png" />
   </head>

 <body>
   <div>
     <header>
       <h1>Page Heading</h1>
     </header>
     <nav>
       <p><a href="/">Home</a></p>
       <p><a href="/contact">Contact</a></p>
     </nav>

     <div>

     </div>

     <footer>
      <p>&copy; Copyright</p>
     </footer>
   </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

But after tidying it, jTidy returns nothing (as in, if the String containing the Tidied HTML is called result, result.equals("") == true)

I have noticed something very interesting though: if I remove everything in the body part of the HTML jTidy works perfectly. Is there something in the <body></body> jTidy doesn't like?

Here is the Java code I am using:

```
 public String tidy(String sourceHTML) {
   StringReader reader = new StringReader(sourceHTML);

   ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
   Tidy tidy = new Tidy();
   tidy.setMakeClean(true);
   tidy.setQuiet(false);
   tidy.setIndentContent(true);
   tidy.setSmartIndent(true);

   tidy.parse(reader, baos);

   try {
     return baos.toString(mEncoding);
   } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
     return null;
   }
 }
```

Is there something wrong with my Java? Is this an error with jTidy? Is there any way I can make jTidy not do this? (I cannot change the HTML). If this absolutely cannot be fixed, are there any other good HTML Tidiers? Thanks very much!

Comment: The only solution I have found is to use HTMLCleaner (http://htmlcleaner.sourceforge.net/), which is really good, I would recommend it if the above is an issue for you.

Comment: I have the same problem. Damn I am having a hard day. First tried the nu.validator, then jcabi-w3c, and now jtidy prints to stderr and I cannot capture the output ... I would hate to use System.setErr

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
tidy.setForceOutput(true);
```

There are probably parse errors.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org/), it's my recommendation for any kind of Java Html processing *(i've used HtmlCleaner to, but then switched to jsoup)*.

**Cleaning Html with Jsoup:**

```
final String yourHtml = ...

String output = Jsoup.clean(yourHtml, Whitelist.relaxed());
```

Thats all!

**Or** (if you want to change / remove / parse / ...) something:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(<file/string/website>, null);

String output = doc.toString();
```